# How to make the subfigures closer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, graphics, table-of-contents

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[row sep=-0.3in]
    \matrix (fig)[matrix of nodes]{
        \includegraphics[width=3in]{1.pdf}  \\
        \includegraphics[width=3in]{2.pdf}    \\
        \includegraphics[width=3in]{3.pdf}    \\};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}
```

I plot three subfigures and wanna keep them closer. Once I set `row sep` a smaller number, the subfigures would overlap with each other, even though there is still some space between them.

Question:

1. how to make them closer without covering the ticks of x and y axles?
2. How to add x and y label for the whole graph?

Comment: It is next-to-impossible to answer the question without seeing the pdf files. BTW, please post a complete example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: [every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}] is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), I guess you have to crop your picture. For 2) I use the `boundingbox`

In order to see how to crop, I wrap the first picture in a `tikzpicture` and added a grid.
Be sure to give a correct value to `row sep`: with your negative value, on my test, pictures obviously overlap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[row sep=-0.3in]
        \matrix (fig)[matrix of nodes]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node {\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}};
                \draw[step=.1,gray, very thin] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
                \draw[step=.5,blue, very thin] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
                \draw[step=1.0, red, thin] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
            \end{tikzpicture}  \\
            \includegraphics[width=3in,clip,trim={5cm 0 0 0}]{example-image-b}\\ % <- just to show trim and clip
            \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-c}\\};
        \path (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) node [pos=.5, below] {x label};
        \path (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.north west) node [pos=.5, left, sloped] {y label};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

Add label on each matrix node.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[row sep=-0.3in]
        \matrix (fig)[matrix of nodes]{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node {\includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-a}};
                \draw[step=.1,gray, very thin] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
                \draw[step=.5,blue, very thin] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
                \draw[step=1.0, red, thin] (current bounding box.south west) grid (current bounding box.north east);
            \end{tikzpicture}  \\
            \includegraphics[width=3in,clip,trim={5cm 0 0 0}]{example-image-b}\\ % <- just to show trim and clip
            \includegraphics[width=3in]{example-image-c}\\};
        \path (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.south east) node [pos=.5, below] {x label};
        \path (current bounding box.south west) -- (current bounding box.north west) node [pos=.5, above=5pt, sloped] {y label};
        \node at (fig-1-1.west) [rotate=90, above=3pt] {label A};
        \node at (fig-2-1.west) [rotate=90, above=3pt] {label B};
        \node at (fig-3-1.west) [rotate=90, above=3pt] {label C};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can I also make separate y labels for each subfigures?

Comment: See the edited answer